# python Keyword matching(keyword list - column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, keyword

supposed dataset,

```
    Name    Value
0   K   Ieatapple
1   Y   bananaisdelicious
2   B   orangelikesomething 
3   Q   bluegrape
4   C   appleislike
```

and I have keyword list like

```
[apple, banana]
```

In this dataset, matching column 'Value' - [keyword list]

*I mean matching is keyword in list in 'Value'

I would like to see how the keywords in the list match column,
so.. I want to find out how much the matching rate is.

Ultimately, what I want to know is
'Finding match rate between keywords and columns'
Percentage, If I can, filtered dataframe

Thank you.

**Edit**

In my real dataset, There are keywords in the sentence,

Ex,

```
Ilikeapplethanbananaandorange
```

so It doesn`t work if use keyword - keyword matching(1:1).

Comment: yes, percentage, and If I can, get matching dataframe.

Comment: Could you show me how apply that ex code?

Comment: df.shape[1]  value is '2', do you mean df.shape[0]? It`s value '5'

Comment: In my real dataset, there are keywords in the sentence.. that code doesn`t work..

Comment: Yes sry, I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.contains` to match words to your sentences:

```
keywords = ['apple', 'banana']
df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(keywords)).sum() / len(df)

# 0.6
```

Or if you want to keep the rows:

```
df[df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(keywords))]

  Name                Value
0    K          I eat apple
1    Y  banana is delicious
4    C          appleislike
```

---

**More details**

The pipe `|` is the `or` operator in regular expression:

So we join our list of words with a pipe to match one of these words:

```
>>> keywords = ['apple', 'banana']
>>> "|".join(keywords)
'apple|banana'
```

So in regular expression we have the statement now:

> *match rows where the sentence contains "apple" OR "banana"*

Comment: Can you explicate "|" is? Is it just mean space?

Comment: See more explanation in my answer after dit.