# Data analysis at keyword matching(List - column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

In my previous task,

[python Keyword matching(keyword list - column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032032/python-keyword-matchingkeyword-list-column)

so It works. further, I want to see the more.

**Question**

**Q1. I want to check the frequency of words in a matched List.**

**output what I want Q1***

*DF*

```
0   K   Ieatapple
1   Y   bananaisdelicious
2   B   orangelikesomething 
3   Q   bluegrape
4   C   appleislike

mylist = [apple, banana]

#keyword matching

df[df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(mylist))]

  Name                Value
0    K          I eat apple
1    Y  banana is delicious
4    C          appleislike

#output what I want
matching word frequency : apple : 2, banana : 1
```

**Q2. I want to check which words in the List match the rows that match the List?**

***output what I want Q2***

Assume the data frame is the same as the example above,

```
  Name                Value
0    K          I eat apple
1    Y  banana is delicious
4    C          appleislike

#Matching keyword&row
0 : apple
1 : banana
4 : apple
```

If you have more than one, I want you to show them all.

Thank you for reading, If you have any questions about my question, ask me plz.

***further***

```
    Value                 New
0   I eat appleapple      apple,apple
1   banana is delicious   banana
2   appleislikeapple      apple,apple
```

I applied below answer and it works very well.
But I got one more thing needed.

As shown in the example above, if there are duplicate words in a row, all of them are found. If the words are duplicated, I want to display only one of them.

By looking for another stackoverflow I've tried ways to remove duplicate words in a row, such as Ordereddict, but it seems to work only in linked sentences.

like `apple apple apple -> apple` 
Does not apply to my case like `apple, apple -> apple, apple`

so when I use below code,

`s = pd.DataFrame (extracted.tolist ()). stack (). value_counts ()`

To count all duplicate words.

How can I solve it?

Comment: @jezrael One more thing needed, and I added it to further. Can you take a look and help if it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want match only one, first matched values use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with joined values in list:

```
df['new'] = df['Value'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(mylist)})', expand=False)
print (df)
  Name                Value     new
0    K          I eat apple   apple
1    Y  banana is delicious  banana
4    C          appleislike   apple
```

And for counts use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['new'].value_counts()
print (s)
apple     2
banana    1
Name: new, dtype: int64

print ('matching word frequency: ' + ', '.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in s.items()))
matching word frequency: apple:2, banana:1
```

If want match all values use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
extracted = df['Value'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})')
df['new'] = extracted.str.join(',')
print (df)
  Name                   Value           new
0    K  I eat apple and banana  apple,banana
1    Y     banana is delicious        banana
4    C             appleislike         apple
```

And for counts use `DataFrame` cosntructor with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `value_counts`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(extracted.tolist()).stack().value_counts()
print (s)
apple     2
banana    2
dtype: int64

print ('matching word frequency: ' + ', '.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in s.items()))
matching word frequency: apple:2, banana:2
```

Comment: Curiosity: does that still work if there were multiple matches per row e.g. first row was `"I eat apple and banana"`?

Comment: @Arnaud - Thanks for notice, answer was also changed for your input.

Comment: @jezrael Are k and v in the syntax simply specified for iterration?

Comment: @ybin - no, it is dictionary comprehension, most time is used `k` and `v` for key and values shorcuts

Comment: @jezrael One more thing needed, and I added it to `further`. Can you take a look and help if it's possible?

Comment: @ybin - change `extracted = df['Value'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})')` to `extracted = df['Value'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})').apply(set)` for sets - it remove duplicated keywords

Comment: @jezrael If use your code, if the value of List is small, it will be put in the new column. But put a list with a size of around 10,000, the new column contains all of the values in Nan, not the values in the matched list. The same goes for removing duplicates with the code just given. What should I do?...

Comment: @ybin - hmmm, it seems data related problem, data are confidental?

Comment: @jezrael yeah, but It is possible to show some and delete them later.

Comment: @ybin - OK, or if possible, sent it to my email

Comment: @jezrael I got it. I`ll send you an email in a minute. Thank you!